# passing data from model to collectionViewCell

Tags: swift, model, uicollectionview, cell

I have several custom cells that are applied through this method

```
 switch indexPath.row {
        case 1:
            cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "randomCell", for: indexPath)
                as? randomCollectionViewCell


        case 2:
            cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "timeCell", for: indexPath)
                as? timeCollectionViewCell

        case 3:
            cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ownerCell", for: indexPath)
                as? ownerCollectionViewCell

default:
            cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath)
                as? imageModelCollectionViewCell

        }
        return cell
    }
```

All cells are displayed simultaneously and sequentially. The last cell that is in the default function is the imageView which I need to pass the value from the model.

The model creates the image as a link, so you also need to upload a picture.

For example this code on like

```
cell.Image Model.image = ...
```

throws an error

```
Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell?'has no member 'modelimage'
```

This is code from collectionViewCell for what i need to passing data

```
import UIKit

class imageModelCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var modelImage: UIImageView!

}
```

How transfer data from model to cell?

//update

i am updating my code by `Saleh Altahini` post

thank you, I try to implement the second method.

i use `var imageModelCell: imageModelCollectionViewCell?`

and use method

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                            self.collectionView.reloadData()

imageModelCell!.modelImage = UIImage(data: data) as imageModelCollectionViewCell }
```

and have an error

```
Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to type 'imageModelCollectionViewCell' in coercion
```

Comment: Can you post code of your cell class?

Comment: it's empty. only output the label and the ImageView
that a problem?

I tried to fill them out but due to lack of working methods erased to avoid code conflicts

Comment: Try this: cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath)
                as! imageModelCollectionViewCell and then cell.image = Model.image btw the first letter of classes in swift have usually a upper case

Comment: No when creating your cell in the datasource make sure you force the downcast with „as!“

Comment: `UIImage(data: data) as imageModelCollectionViewCell` is causing the error because you're trying to downcast an _UIImage_ to _imageModelCollectionViewCell_. Try removing the `as imageModelCollectionViewCell`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting means that your cell is not downcasted to `imageModelCollectionViewCell`. Maybe you're not referencing the cell correctly?

Anyway, you can setup the cell in two ways.
first method is to setup your cell in the `cellForItemAt` function like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath) as! imageModelCollectionViewCell
    cell.modelImage.image = //Your Image
    return cell
}
```

Or you can reference your cell at the beginning and set it up later from anywhere else. Just add a variable like `var imageModelCell: imageModelCollectionViewCell` to the *UICollectionViewDataSource* and pass the cell in the `cellForItemAt` like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath) as! imageModelCollectionViewCell
    self.imageModelCell = cell
    return cell
}
```

you can then just use `imageModelCell.modelImage = //Your Image` from any other function or callback

A side note: it's a good practice to start the name of your classes with a capital letter and variables with a small letter, so you can better differentiate what you're calling or referencing with Xcode. Maybe consider changing the name of you class to *ImageModelCollectionViewCell*.

Comment: that's because you're placing it in an extension. If you're just using an extension to manage your CollectionView you need to change it from an extension to a class instance and put the var at the start of the class like `class NameOfClass : ViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{ var imageModelCell: imageModelCollectionViewCell`

Comment: i am update info in post under mark `//update`
can u look?